# Using objects as functions

Tags: python, function, oop

I'm going through a Python OOPs book by Dusty Phillips. I fail to understand a particular program in the book, chapter 7 - Python Object-oriented Shortcuts. The extended version of the code is available  [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Python-3-Object-Oriented-Programming-Third-Edition/blob/master/Chapter07/event_timer.py)

Although the program comes under the topic **Functions are objects too**, the provided program also uses a strange code, which i feel, more of imply the opposite (using objects as functions).

I have pointed out the line in the code where i have the doubt. How is that variable `callback` of `TimedEvent` used like a function `Timer` class ? What is going on here in this part.

```
import datetime
import time

class TimedEvent:
    def __init__(self, endtime, callback):
        self.endtime = endtime
        self.callback = callback

    def ready(self):
        return self.endtime <= datetime.datetime.now()

class Timer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.events = []

    def call_after(self, delay, callback):
        end_time = datetime.datetime.now() + \
        datetime.timedelta(seconds=delay)
        self.events.append(TimedEvent(end_time, callback))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            ready_events = (e for e in self.events if e.ready())
            for event in ready_events:
                event.callback(self)               ----------------> Doubt
                self.events.remove(event)
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Well how is `callback` initialised? You don’t show that part. Is a *function* assigned to it? Or something else?

Comment: You can see it in the __init__ of TimedEvent. But I was wondering how its being used for calling other objects! And by the way, the full code is provided in a link as well. The only 'callback' in the code is the one I mentioned.

Comment: That’s insufficient, because we don’t know how `call_after` is called! Looking at the linked code, `call_after` is always invoked with a regular function for `callback`. So `callback` … just contains a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are true

- functions are objects: do a `dir(f)` on a function to view its attributes
- objects can be used as functions: just add `__call__(self, ...)` method and use the object like a function.

In general things that can be called using a syntax like `whatever(x, y, z)` are called *callables*.

What the example is trying to show is that *methods* are **just object attributes that are also callables**. Just like you can write `obj.x = 5`, you can also write `obj.f = some_function`.

Comment: Are they really methods? Not just functions stored as attributes?

Comment: [Python's glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method) defines "method" as "A function which is defined inside a class body. [...]", and here they're top-level functions.

Comment: @superbrain: that's complicated. Functions become methods when they are looked up using `object.f`. A method is a function that has already been passed the `self` argument (that's the important part of the definition, doesn't matter where they are defined). Look into the *descriptor protocol* on how that happens. Descriptors are really interesting, they explain various aspects of python.

Comment: But that's rather an argument **against** these being methods, as `self` is passed explicitly there. No?

Comment: `self` is written explicitly in the code, but it's not passed by the programmer, it's passed by the interpreter. That happens using the descriptor protocol when the function is looked up using the dot. But, it's really complicated, if you are interested look into descriptors.

Comment: But that would give the functions two arguments, and they only take one. That would cause an error.

Comment: Just to be sure: You've seen that they have functions like [this](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Python-3-Object-Oriented-Programming-Third-Edition/blob/44a6a35318afcbfb49bb0ef981a81d66b28f247b/Chapter07/event_timer.py#L39), which are stored as attribute with `self.callback = callback` (where the right-hand `callback` is that function), and then later called?

Comment: @superbrain: you're right, I messed up when reading it. Will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that example indeed shows that functions are object. You can assign an object to the `callback` attribute and this tries to show that the object you assign to `callback` can be a function.

```
class TimedEvent:
    def __init__(self, endtime, callback):
        self.endtime = endtime
        self.callback = callback
```

What is missing to make it clear is the initialization. You could, for example, do this:

```
def print_current_time():
    print(datetime.datetime.now().isoformat())

event = TimedEvent(endtime, print_current_time)
event.callback()
```

This will actually call `print_current_time`, because `event.callback` is `print_current_time`.